# computation of $\int_0^T \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need approaches to solve the problem of the following type 
$\int_{0}^{T} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt $. Is there a closed form solution available.

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ can't be integrated in the sense that it's integral can't be expressed as a combination of a finite number of elementary functions.

Comment: @RaM1188 The use of $T$ suggests that this shows up as part of some kind of problem related to periodic functions. If that's the case, I suggest you put all the info in the question.

Comment: @GitGud sorry there is no periodicity. The T is any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral
$$
\int_0^T\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
is called the [Sine Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral). It has no closed form in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

However, its limit as $T\to\infty$ is
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac\pi2
$$

Comment: Dear Rob, I had a very old account here. I lost my pass and user name for it and in fact I lost it. Could it be merged with my currently profile? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS.: I don't see any such account. You should contact the Community Team using the [contact us link](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) below.

Comment: I 'll do that. Thanks. May I give you the link indicating that account?

Comment: If you can't merge using the [Merge user profiles page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge), you will need to [contact the Community Team](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact).